# How to do that would hasPermission did not check the field id?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, acl

I have some controller:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/createOrUpdate.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#message, 'CREATE')")
public String form(@Valid final Message message, final Model model) {
    if (message.getId() == null) {
        someService.save(message);
        AclManager.create(message);
    } else {
        someService.update(message);
        AclManager.update(message);
    }
    return "main";
}
```

This controller use for two purposes - if message.id == null, it creates a new record, if message.id != null, then the record is updated.

My problem is when message.id == null, I get an exception because "hasPermission" requires that all fields have been filled.

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/portal].[mvc-dispatcher]] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-3) Servlet.service() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: getId() is required to return a non-null value
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112) [spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ObjectIdentityImpl.<init>(ObjectIdentityImpl.java:86) [spring-security-acl-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ObjectIdentityRetrievalStrategyImpl.getObjectIdentity(ObjectIdentityRetrievalStrategyImpl.java:34) [spring-security-acl-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.acls.AclPermissionEvaluator.hasPermission(AclPermissionEvaluator.java:57) [spring-security-acl-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot.hasPermission(SecurityExpressionRoot.java:129) [spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69) [spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:197) [spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102) [spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:98) [spring-expression-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:11) [spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.before(ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice.java:41) [spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:54) [spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.vote(PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter.java:24) [spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:62) [spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206) [spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:60) [spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631) [spring-aop-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at com.payplaza.pms.portal.system.controllers.AcquirerController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1069f3c6_2.form(<generated>) [spring-core-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801) [spring-webmvc-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar:3.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
```

How fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use ternary operator:

```
@PreAuthorize("#message.id!=null ? hasPermission(#message, 'UPDATE') : hasPermission(#message, 'CREATE')")
```

I suppose that you have corresponding 'UPDATE' permission for update case.

Comment: But as I understand it, it will give the opportunity to create new records for all users, inspection permissions will only if the message != null

Comment: It looks good. I'm using: @PreAuthorize("#message.id!=null ? hasPermission(#message, 'WRITE') : hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") But there is a problem when I click on the button that activates the controller, I get: HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported You know what it could be?

Comment: For example form may be submitted to some another controller that does not support post method. Post another question with more details.